# Linux Disk Monitor, allways busy even not in use

Tags: linux

I'm trying to read the disk activity on some nvme disks in my system, using nmon, however they only ever show up as: `disk busy not available`.

What tools can I use to debug this? (I know for a fact they're doing nothing particular).